# Adding subitemID column in the Sales Prices Grid but I get an error

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to add the subitemID column in the grid of the sales prices screen, I already added it but I get an error when opening the screen, see the screenshot below:

[image]

This is the error:

```
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Inventory ID: Specified cast is not valid..

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at PX.Data.PXDataRecord.GetInt32(Int32 i) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Record.cs:line 458
   at PX.Data.PXDBIdentityAttribute.RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Descriptor\Attributes\DBFieldAttribute.cs:line 4624
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Cache\ModelEventHandling.cs:line 399
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Cache\ModelEventHandling.cs:line 315
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Select(PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean& wasUpdated) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Cache\Model.cs:line 3932
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Cached.cs:line 3588
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Cached.cs:line 5943
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARSalesPriceMaint.QSelect(PXGraph graph, BqlCommand bqlCommand, Object[] viewParameters) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\AR\ARSalesPriceMaint.cs:line 183
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARSalesPriceMaint.d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\AR\ARSalesPriceMaint.cs:line 154
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__95`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at PX.Data.PXView.ToList(IEnumerable src) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Cached.cs:line 6458
   at _CustomMethod(Object , Object[] )
   at PX.Data.PXView.InvokeDelegate(Object[] parameters) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Cached.cs:line 6508
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Database\Cached.cs:line 5862
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Data\Graph\Graph.cs:line 3422
```

These are the attributes of the SubItemID column:

```
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="SubItemID")]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.defaultSubItemID,
    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>>,
    And<InventoryItem.defaultSubItemOnEntry, Equal<boolTrue>>>>),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Default<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>))]
[SubItem(typeof(ARSalesPrice.inventoryID))]
[SubItemStatusVeryfier(typeof(ARSalesPrice.inventoryID), typeof(ARSalesPrice.siteID), InventoryItemStatus.Inactive, InventoryItemStatus.NoSales)]
```

I want to creat it like the Sales Orders screen, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: It may be, but are you sure the issue is the subitem field?  The error specifically states "the field Inventory ID".  Is there more detail in the trace?

Comment: Not that it would make a difference but because you have the SubItemAttribute on your field you do not need the PXDBInt or PXUIField attributes. Remove those just to see if makes a difference.

Comment: I just removed the PXDBInt or PXUIField attributes but I still get the same error. I dont know if  there is any event handler causing that. @Brendan

Comment: when you get that error go to the Tools menu on the page and click Trace for more details and trace details. Paste the trace details to your post for more detail

Comment: I just added the detailed error @Brendan, thanks

Comment: I just added the detailed error @BrianStevens, thanks

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado could you please add the property of the SubItemID in the code and the definition of the column in the SQL? This error usually means that you have used different types in one of the following places : Field Type Attribute, Property Type, SQL Column, Bql Column class